# Automated release to Maven Central with Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I'd like to upload my jar to the Maven Central repository using `gradle uploadArchives` and use it in other projects as a dependency.
I've followed this nice [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20190214130235/http://yennicktrevels.com/blog/2013/10/11/automated-gradle-project-deployment-to-sonatype-oss-repository/) with the result that my jars are uploaded to Sonatype Nexus (see screenshot below).

The 0.1 version of my jar is available; the line

`dependencies {compile 'eu.matthiasbraun:Utils:0.1'}`

works just fine in the `build.gradle` file of my dependent project. I released the 0.1 version by clicking the <kbd>Close</kbd> and the <kbd>Release</kbd> buttons seen in the screenshot. After that I commented on the Jira ticket I had created [here](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/OSSRH-7909) and was told that central sync would run every two hours.

It was my understanding that if I now wanted to release the 0.2 version of my jar, I simply would do `gradle uploadArchives` and change the line in build.gradle` of my dependent project to

`dependencies {compile 'eu.matthiasbraun:Utils:0.2'}`.

Yet, when I `gradle build` my dependent project (after two hours) I got the error that the dependency could not be resolved.

Here's my complete `build.gradle` which uploads my jar to Sonatype Nexus: [link](https://pastebin.com/pDhMa3h9).

How can I automate the release of jars to Maven Central using Gradle?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've used the [nexus-workflow gradle plugin](https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/plugins-gradle) to automate the releasing of repositories.

I put this at the top of the `build.gradle` of my project I want to release:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.adaptc.gradle:nexus-workflow:0.6'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'nexus-workflow'
```

Additionally I put these three properties in `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

```
oss-releases.username=mySonatypeUsername
oss-releases.password=mySonatypePassword
oss-releases.url=https://oss.sonatype.org/index.html#stagingRepositories
```

When I want to push a release to Maven Central, I first upload the jars to Nexus using `gradle uploadArchives` and then I do `gradle nexusStagingRelease`. This closes and releases all my open repos on Nexus.

---

Edit:
I also found [this plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-nexus-plugin) by Benjamin Muschko which seems to be an alternative to the plugin described above. I didn't try it yet, though.

Comment: Nice to see that there is a community created gradle plugin already as well ;-)

Comment: nexus-workflow looks fine, but gradle-nexus-plugin by Benjamin Muschko simplified only uploading archives to Nexus. Releasing/promoting to Maven Central is [not supported](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-nexus-plugin/issues/40). [Gradle Nexus Staging Plugin](https://github.com/Codearte/gradle-nexus-staging-plugin/) can be used as an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

[Gradle Nexus Staging Plugin](https://github.com/Codearte/gradle-nexus-staging-plugin/) can be used to automatize closing the repository and promote/release artifacts to Maven Central.

It has to be added to your project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.codearte.gradle.nexus:gradle-nexus-staging-plugin:0.5.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'io.codearte.nexus-staging'
```

and configured:

```
nexusStaging {
    packageGroup = "org.mycompany.myproject"
    stagingProfileId = "yourStagingProfileId" //optional, but reduce number of calls to Nexus
}
```

After the artifacts were uploaded (with `uploadArchives` or any other way) it is enough to call:

```
./gradlew closeRepository promoteRepository
```

If a synchronization with Maven Central was enabled the artifacts should automatically appear into Maven Central within several minutes.

More information (including the ways how credentials can be provided) in that [blog post](https://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/automatic-promotion-of-artifacts-to-maven-central-from-gradle/) or on the [project webpage](https://github.com/Codearte/gradle-nexus-staging-plugin/).

Disclaimer. I am the author of this plugin.

Comment: How would one fire the tasks in a multi project setup?

Comment: Just put it in the root project to call once. gradle-nexus-staging-plugin just calls Nexus and close/release the staging repository. There could be any artifacts put before. Even from the other Gradle project (if you had a wish to do that).

Comment: There is even an entry in the README: https://github.com/Codearte/gradle-nexus-staging-plugin/#multi-project-build

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows that you have not yet released you library. You have only staged it to OSSRH. What you need to do next is to

- Close the staging repository by pressing the 'Close' button, this signals to Nexus that nothing else is expected to be added to the staging repository
- verify the files in the content are ok
- if you are happy with everything - release the components to Central by pressing the 'Release' button,
- or if you are unhappy with it press 'Drop' button to delete the staging repo and start from scratch
- waiting till everything is synced to Central from OSSRH (takes up to an hour or a bit more depending on your timing)

Btw. if you can automate this on the command line with the Nexus Staging Maven Plugin or the Ant Tasks. And you can wrap the Ant tasks and use them in Gradle. More info about all this is in the [staging chapter of the Nexus book](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/staging.html).

Comment: Thanks, but as a Gradle/Maven/Ant beginner I would have a hard time wrapping those tasks. This is why I prefer the nexus-workflow plugin.

Comment: Fair enough and I am glad this plugin exists ;-)